# Green's representation for the Helmholtz equation in arbitrary dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, elliptic-equations

I am looking for a reference containing a proof of Green's representation formula in $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} \Phi_x - u\frac{\partial \Phi_x}{\partial \nu} \, dS,$$
where $u$ is a solution of the $n$-dimensional Helmholtz equation, $\Phi_x$ the radiating fundamental solution centred at $x$ and $D$ a suitable domain with unit normal $\nu$.

I have only been able to find a proof for $n=3$: Theorems 2.1 and 2.5 of [this book](https://www.google.at/books/edition/Inverse_Acoustic_and_Electromagnetic_Sca/Jc-8DwAAQBAJ?hl=de&gbpv=0).

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of green function and theorem for PDEs has a standard approach. You can find analytical proofs in mathematical textbooks like [L.Evans book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC) (chapter 2), but specific proofs especially with vector calculus analysis are more likely to be found in physics literatures. for examplt see :

1. [Green’s Functions in Classical Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Green_s_Functions_in_Classical_Physics/enEiyQEACAAJ?hl=en) by Rother
2. [Scalar wave theory, Green's function and applications](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Scalar_Wave_Theory/qJaDzQEACAAJ?hl=en) by DeSanto
3. [Classical Electrodynamics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Classical_Electrodynamics/yt8NAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=electrodynamics%20jackson&dq=electrodynamics%20jackson&printsec=frontcover) by jackson

proof for Helmholtz is not different from general Sturm-Liouvill problem or the Laplace PDE, that's why no book will specifically mention it.

---

But since there's standard pattern for proof of this, I'm going to write it here;

Assume $\phi_{x'}$ satisfies the Helmholtz equation,
$$
\tag{1} \label{1}
\Delta \phi _ {x'}(x) + k^2 \phi _ {x'}(x) = \delta(x-x') \quad x \in \mathcal{D} \subset\mathbb{R}^n,
$$ 
where $\delta(x-x')$ is dirac delta function, i.e.
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}
\int_\mathcal{D'} f(x)\delta (x-x') d \mathbf{x} = f(x')
$$
for all (continuous compactly supported) functions $f$, where $x' \in \mathcal{D'}$.

from [green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green%27s_second_identity), we have
$$
\tag{3} \label{3}
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathcal{D}} \big( \psi \Delta \phi - \phi \Delta \psi \big) d\mathbf{x} &= \int_{\partial \mathcal{D}} (\phi \nabla\psi - \psi \nabla\phi ).d\mathbf{S}
\\
& = \int_{\partial \mathcal{D}} (\phi \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \nu} - \psi \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \nu})ds.
\end{align}
$$
you can find proof of this in calculus or vector analysis books.

Consider $u$ is solution of homogenous Helmholtz equation,
$$
\tag{4}\label{4}
\Delta u + k^2u=0.
$$
Start with $\ref{3}$ for $u$ and $\phi_{x'}$ and use $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{4}$, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathcal{D}} (u \Delta \phi_{x'} - \phi_{x'} \Delta u ) d \mathbf{x} &= \int_{\mathcal{D}} \bigg[ u . \underbrace{(-k^2 \phi_{x'} + \delta(x-x'))}_{\Delta \phi_{x'}} - \phi_{x'}. \underbrace{(-k^2 u)}_{\Delta u} \bigg] d \mathbf{x} \\
& = \int_{\mathcal{D}} u(x) \delta(x-x') d \mathbf{x} \\
\stackrel{\text{using }\ref{2}}{=} u(x') &= \int_{\partial \mathcal{D}} (\phi_{x'} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} - u \frac{\partial \phi_{x'}}{\partial \nu} )ds.
\end{align}
$$